# Accessing prematch, match and postmatch in Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

When matching a regular expression in Perl, [three variables named `$PREMATCH`, `$MATCH` and `$POSTMATCH` are set](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#VARIABLES), containing the parts of the input string before the match, the match itself, and the part after.

How can I access the same values using Python regular expressions?

Comment: I think he means syntactic shortcuts (not just `re.match`, etc). There aren't

Comment: I was able to emulate Perl Pre/Post matching this way : `>>> aa = re.compile(r'(?P<prematch>.*?)(?P<match>mystring)(?P<postmatch>.*)')` then `>>bb="some_stuffmystring_mystringsomestuff"` and finally `>>> aa.match(bb).group('prematch','match','postmatch')` gives ('some_stuff', 'mystring', '_mystringsomestuff')

Answer (score 5):

No, Python has no explicit support for prematch and postmatch values, but you *can* use the attributes of a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) to slice the input string; given a matchobject `match`, the equivalents are:

- `$PREMATCH`: `match.string[:match.start()]`
- `$MATCH`: `match.group()`
- `$POSTMATCH`: `match.string[match.end():]`

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.search(r'\d+', 'Pre 1234 Post')
>>> match.string[:match.start()]
'Pre '
>>> match.group()
'1234'
>>> match.string[match.end():]
' Post'
```

You could also use [`re.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) to divvie up a string around a regular expression with a group around the whole expression:

```
>>> re.split(r'(\d+)', 'Pre 1234 Post')
['Pre ', '1234', ' Post']
```

You can use tuple-unpacking to put that into variables if you like:

```
>>> pre, match, post = re.split(r'(\d+)', 'Pre 1234 Post')
>>> pre, post
('Pre ', ' Post')
>>> match
'1234'
```

Do be aware that `.split()` will keep on splitting unless you limit it to 1 match with the `maxsplit` parameter:

```
>>> re.split(r'(\d+)', 'One 1 Two 2 Three 3')
['One ', '1', ' Two ', '2', ' Three ', '3', '']
>>> re.split(r'(\d+)', 'One 1 Two 2 Three 3', 1)
['One ', '1', ' Two 2 Three 3']
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you use the `re` module in python. The syntax is however a bit different than in Perl, there are no shortcuts as in Perl.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can for example use groups.

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv'
>>> match = re.search('(.*)ij(.*)', str)
>>> match.groups()
('abcdefgh', 'klmnopqrstuv')
>>>
```